# Timeout for broadcasting message using SignalR

Tags: signalr

I am using SignalR for the 1st time in my asp.net c# web app.

I am using HTML 5 and JavaScript for my client web page.

In essence whenever my server has an image to 'push' to my clients it does so.  Sometimes this can be quite frequent.

Now, I imagine during a 'busy' period' my client(s) could be 'over-whelmed' by the data being pushed by my server?

How does my server know that the message has been recieved by my client (or not) and then proceed to send the next one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SignalR doesn't provide a built-in way to wait for a client to receive a message. This would be very difficult to do in the general case where someone might be using `Clients.All`, and clients might be connecting/reconnecting/disconnecting at the time the message is sent.

However, it is possible to manually acknowledge that you have received a message on the client (perhaps by calling some hub method on the server), and then continue to send the next message once the acknowledgement (ACK) for the previous one has been received.

Comment: Hi, great minds think a like. :) That is what I am doing now. It would be what I would do if I was using TCP/Sockets.  I thought I would ask the question here to see if I had other options. Thanks for your reasoning :)

Comment: Out of curiosity. How are you pushing the images to your clients? Are you pushing a URL?

Comment: Hi, no I push it as a byte array then load as base64 to an image element.

Comment: Just be aware the SignalR will [buffer the last 1000 messages](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/performance/signalr-performance#tuning) sent to any given destination in an in-memory ring buffer by default. This can of course lead to high memory usage if you are sending a lot of large messages.

Comment: Hi, that is very informative. I have changed my method to not send the array to the client but just a zero or one to indicate whether an image is available. If so then I use a generic handler to download the image.  Is there a way to flush this buffer?